# Converting string to array in es6

Tags: javascript, split

How do i convert the following string input 
`name: xyz friend: abc mobile: 123`
into an array separating it as something like this
`[{key:"name", value:"xyz"}]`

I have tried this code for splitting

```
let friend1 = 
'name:xyz 
friend:abc 
mobile_no:123'
let Array=friend1.split(" ");
console.log(Array)`
```

need help with the `key and value` part.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper data structure like JSON instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. To remove colliding colon + whitespace pairs `:`, I replace them with `####`
2. Then split the array on the rest of whitespaces
3. For each split, being in this case `name####xyz`, `friend####abc` and `mobile####123`, split them on `####` and construct desired object

```js
let string = "name: xyz friend: abc mobile: 123";
let array  = string
  .replace(/:\s/g, '####')
  .split(' ')
  .map(pair => {

    let split = pair.split('####');
    return { key: split[0], value: split[1] };

  });
  
console.log(array)
```

Comment: But you don't have to make it that easy. How would you break `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Define "break". In that case, for me, `JSON.parse("name: xyz friend: abc mobile: 123")` is "broken". Nvm. I can only assume it is going to be used to parse some chunks of data stored locally, and not in production code. And as you can see, it helped.

Comment: Passing invalid inputs to a function which then by specification fails to parse it is not the same as breaking it. Breaking in this context means that with a given input, the function produces something that was not specified. e.g. `name: x y`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! was struggling with this for a whole day.

Comment: Was trying to solve this for a brief period.. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

If the input itself is an array, then this will do the object(dictionary) conversion

```
var targetDictionary = {};
var string = ["name: xyz", "friend: abc", "mobile: 123"];
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var split = string[i].split(':');
    targetDictionary[split[0]] = split[1];
}
```